# no entiendo esta clase

Tags: c++

estoy leyendo un libro de estructuras de datos se llama Open Data Structures (in C++)
en la página 44 tiene esta parte

> In this chapter, and throughout this book, it will be convenient to have
> arrays that keep track of their size. The usual C++ arrays do not do this,
> so we have defined a class, array, that keeps track of its length. The
> implementation of this class is straightforward. It is implemented as a
> standard C++ array, a, and an integer, length:
> y los siguientes códigos
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que me esta generando dudas esto es el codigo completo porque para mi que le falta algo

Comment: Bienvenido(a) a SOes. El código no debería mostrarse a través de imágenes, recuerda que no todos podemos verlo. Te invito a que [edites](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/558709/edit) tu pregunta y pongas el código con su respectivo formato. Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: ¿Qué crees que le falta o qué es lo que no entiendes?

Comment: si, ya sabia esa regla lo que pasa es que no se iba a entender porque esta cortado

Comment: @Mateo cuandop se declara una clase se pone 
class nombre{...etc 
y aca no hay nada de eso

Comment: Ah sí. Las clases se declaran así como dices. Simplemente quien haya escrito el libro decidió darlo por sentado y se concentró en lo importante, que son los campos de la clase y algunos operadores.

Answer (score 3):

El libro que estás leyendo o es **muy** antiguo o está mintiendo (A juzgar por el uso de `NULL` en lugar de `nullptr` podría ser previo a 2011). C++ **sí** que dispone estructuras de datos que guardan información de su tamaño: casi todos los [contenedores de la STL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) (*standard template library*) lo hacen y estos contenedores son bastante previos a 2011.

Respecto a lo que falta en ese código:

1. A la clase le falta la definición y los datos de plantilla.

   ```
   template <typename T>
   class array { ... };
   ```
2. Los miembros `a` y `length` deben tener inicializadores por defecto y `length` debe ser de tipo `std::size_t`:

   ```
   template <typename T>
   class array {
       T *a{nullptr};
       std::size_t length{};
   };
   ```
3. Se necesita un constructor por defecto definido por el compilador y sería conveniente un constructor que reciba una `std::initializer_list`:

   ```
   template <typename T>
   class array {
       T *a{nullptr};
       std::size_t length{};
   public:
       array() = default;
       array(const std::initializer_list<T> &il) :
           length{il.length()}
       {
           a = new T[length];
           std::copy(il.begin(), il.end(), a);
       }
   };
   ```
4. El operador de asignación está mal definido ya que usa `NULL`, no optimiza para copias de `array` del mismo tamaño, usa la cualificación de clase completa cuando en el contexto de la propia clase es innecesario y modifica el `array` de entrada cuando una copia debería dejarlo intacto:

   ```
   template <typename T>
   class array {
       T *a{nullptr};
       std::size_t length{};
   public:
       // ...
       array &operator =(const array &b)
       {
           if (length != b.length)
           {
               delete[] a;
               length = b.length;
               a = new T[length];
           }

           std::copy(b.a, b.a + b.length, a);
       }
   };
   ```
5. Probablemente en el anterior punto quería implementar un operador de movimiento:

   ```
   template <typename T>
   class array {
       T *a{nullptr};
       std::size_t length{};
   public:
       // ...
       array &operator =(array &&b)
       {
           std::swap(b.a, a);
           a.length = b.length;
       }
   };
   ```
6. El operador de indexado debería tener una versión constante:

   ```
   template <typename T>
   class array {
       // ...
   public:
       // ...
       T &operator[](std::size_t index)
       {
           assert(index < length);
           return a[index];
       }
       const T &operator[](std::size_t index) const
       {
           assert(index < length);
           return a[index];
       }
   };
   ```

Esto son sólo algunas de las cosas que le faltan, podríamos añadir varias más pero no vale la pena: usa un `std::vector` que es exactamente lo mismo que está implementando el libro, pero mucho mejor.

Comment: mil gracias mas o menos es lo que veia yo